# How do I say "It's alright"?

Tags: mandarin, traditional-characters

How does one say "it's okay" or "it's alright" along the lines of "it's fine, don't lose hope". It could be a consolation or someone brushing something off going "Oh, it's still okay".

Could someone include the pinyin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**没事**

méi​shì

**[MDBG](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?page=worddict&wdrst=0&wdqb=%E6%B2%A1%E4%BA%8B)​**

> it's not important / it's nothing / never mind / to have nothing to do / to be free / to be all right (out of danger or trouble)

---

**没关系**

méi​guān​xi​

**[MDBG](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?page=worddict&wdrst=0&wdqb=%E6%B2%92%E9%97%9C%E4%BF%82)**

> it doesn't matter